# Multiple controls with the same ID 'DXSelBtn0' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I got this error when i press a button, but i searched for that ID 'DXSelBtn0' i couldn't find it. Button is a Devexpress button, and i just add click event to it thats all. When i delete the event, i don't get that error. What should i do?

Thanks
Mehmet Şerif Tozlu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you create unbound columns instead as it is described in the topic available at:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3732

Comment: I tried unbound columns but i still get question marks so i cannot select those fields, am i missing something?

Comment: I don't want to use Edit mode of the AspxGridView, instead of that i want user to select those unbound columns without getting into the edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the button programatically, make sure you explicitly set the Id of the control to something unique. Or if you are in a loop, make sure you explicitly define a unique id for each control.

Comment: I don't create the button programatically, here is the code to create it :
<dxe:ASPxButton ID="btnAddToList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False"
                    OnClick="btnAddToList_Click" Text="Listeye Ekle" ClientInstanceName="btnAdd">
</dxe:ASPxButton>

When i delete OnClick="btnAddToList_Click", i don't get the error.

Comment: Are you using any other DevExpress controls? You say removing the event handler fixes the problem, but do you see the problem when you click the button, or just on a normal page load? What are you attempting to do in the click event?

Comment: Yes, i use other Devexpress controls but there is only one Button control. When i click the button i see the error page. On page load there is no problem. I try to get selected rows' values of an AspxGridView control on the click event.

Answer (score 0):

The DXSelBtn is a prefix used to generate IDs for select checkBoxes in the command column of the ASPxGridView.  I tend to think that you are manipulating the grid in some way.  Sorry, it is impossible to tell what causes this issue without your code.